# Post XML to WebAPI

Tags: xml, asp.net-web-api, asp-classic, jscript

I am calling the Web API Method from Classic asp as Below. But I always get requestData null in API rather than XML.

Classic ASP code calling the Web API:

```js
var XMLOrder = new ActiveXObject ("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
XMLOrder.load("orderTemplate.xml");
var xHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xHttp.Open("POST","http://localhost:18977/SaveActitvityRequest",false);       
xHttp.setRequestHeader("CONTENT-TYPE", "application/xml")       
xHttp.Send(XMLOrder);
```

Web API Method:

```cs
[Route("SaveActitvityRequest")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage SaveActitvityRequest([FromBody]XDocument requestData)
{
    try
    {
        return null;
    }       
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: @matt_lethargic  one question regarding above example...I am returning HttpResponseMessage  from webapi..but in above Classic ASP code from where i called api..i want to retrieve data from Response.in classic asp

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, do not modify your question (to add in the answer), to then be an entirely different question and issue.

Answer (score 2):

requestData is probably null because you're sending an instance of the 'Microsoft.XMLDOM' object. If you try sending the xml instead it should start working. Change the last line of your classic asp to:

```
xHttp.Send(XMLOrder.xml);
```